# How to centre a table in a two column document

Tags: tables, footnotes, threeparttable

I have a table in a two-column document. I want to center it. I used `\centring` but it does not bring the table to the center. It was correctly centered when I used `resizebox` but I had to comment it because it caused me errors after I added `\begin{threeparttable}`.

My problem: how to enable `resizebox` to work correctly with the `\begin{threeparttable}`? or how to center the table without the `resizebox`?

Here is a picture:

[image]
Here is my script:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{underscore} %for underscores
\usepackage[font=itshape]{quoting} %for double quotation
\usepackage{graphicx} %for images
\usepackage{epstopdf} %for images in eps files
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for th \textquotesingle
\usepackage{amsmath} %used in subequations
\usepackage{pbox} %for parbox
\usepackage{placeins} %for \FloatBarrier before references
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable, tablefootnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{table*}[tb!] 
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{My Table}
\label{table:my-table}
\centering
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular} {lc*{16}l }
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} 
 &&\multicolumn{3}{c}{B}    
 &&\multicolumn{3}{c}{C}  
 &&\multicolumn{3}{c}{D}  
 &&\multicolumn{2}{c}{E}  

\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} 
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} 
\cmidrule(lr){7-9}
\cmidrule(lr){11-13}
\cmidrule(lr){15-16}
\\
& \vline &\rot{A} & \rot{B} & \rot{C} 
& \vline & \rot{AAA} & \rot{BBB} & \rot{CCC} 
& \vline & \rot{AAA} & \rot{BBB} &\rot{CCC} 
& \vline & \rot{AAA} & \rot{BBB} 

\\ \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} 
A &\vline  & {} & {}     & {}     & \vline  & {}     & {}  & {}      & \vline  & {} &{}  & & \vline &    & \cmark \tnote{1}   \\

B     &\vline  & {}     & {} & {}     & \vline  & {}     & {}   & {}      & \vline & {} & {} & & \vline & {} & \cmark\tnote{1}   \\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
C & \vline & {} & {}     & {}     & \vline  & {}     & {}   & {}      & \vline & {} &{}  & &\vline & {} & {}    \\

D & \vline & {} & {}    & {}     & \vline   & {}     & {}   & {}      & \vline & {} &{}  & &\vline & {} & {}  \\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9} 
E      & \vline & {}     & {} & {}    & \vline   & {}  & {}      & {}      & \vline & {} & {} & &\vline & {} & {}    \\

F                           & \vline & {} & {}    & {}     & \vline   & {}  & {}      & {}      & \vline & {}     & {} & & \vline & {} & \cmark   \\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
G        & \vline & {} & {}    & {}     & \vline   & {}  & {}      & {}       & \vline & {} & {}    & & \vline & {} & {}  \\

H         & \vline & {} & {}   & {}     & \vline    & {}     & {}   & {}      & \vline  & {}     &{}& & \vline & {} & {}  \\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
I & \vline & {}     & {}     & {} & \vline & {}  & {}  & {}       & \vline  & {}     &{} & & \vline & {} & {} \\

J       & \vline & {}     & {}     & {} & \vline & {}      & {}      & {}   & \vline  & {}     &{} & &\vline & {} & \cmark   \\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
K &\vline  & {}     & {} & {}     & \vline  & {}     & {}   & {}      & \vline & {} & {} & & \vline & {} & {}  \\

L & \vline & {}     & {} & {}    & \vline   & {}  & {}      & {}      & \vline & {} & {} & &\vline & {} & {}    \\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
M & \vline & {}  & {} & {}    & \vline   & {}  & {} & {}  & \vline & {} & {} &{} &\vline  & {} &{} \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
%}%end resize boxs
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item [1] A cute little footnote
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `\centering` is on wrong place. Move it immediately after `\begin{table}`:

```
...
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{table*}
    \centering         % had to be here!
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{My Table}
\label{table:my-table}
\begin{tabular} {lc*{16}l }
\hline
...
```

[image]